# Detect element height changes and hide if too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, height

I am working with a payment gateway widget and need to detect when its height had changed. To do this, I need to target the first `.col-xs-12` within my container and detect if its height has changed.

If its height has changed, I then need to check if the height is less than `310px`.

If that is the case, I need the whole row to hide.

I have tried what you see below but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
var $paywhirlWidget = $("#payment-signup-section .container .row .col-xs-12:first-child"),
  lastHeight = $("#payment-signup-section .container .row .col-xs-12:first-child").height();

function checkForChanges() {
  if ($paywhirlWidget.height() != lastHeight) {
    if($paywhirlWidget.height() <= 310) {
        $paywhirlWidget.css("display", "none");
    }
    lastHeight = $paywhirlWidget.height();
  }
}

setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
```

Comment: A couple things I notice right off the bat are that you are using setTimeout, which only executes one time. You would be looking for the function setInterval to keep checking if the size updates. What would probably be more helpful, though is the jquery .resize() function. This will trigger when an element is resized. I have not tested it yet, but that would be my first instinct. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: @mhodges the setInterval sorted it! good lad, if you post that comment as an answer, I will upvote and mark correct! cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request: A couple things I notice right off the bat are that you are using setTimeout, which only executes one time. You would be looking for the function setInterval() to keep checking if the size updates.